# How to read cryptowatch?

Tags: trading, charts

I'm a complete newbie to crypto, and to trading, and I would like to be able to understand what the lines and charts mean on cryptowatch. I know this is a tall order to collect and collate, but I imagine other people wonder about this as well.

In order to make the discussion easier, i've made a labeled snapshot of their output.

[image]

Help me understand what these labeled charts display and mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yO-W_GDwZrg&t=497s

This video will walk you through the different aspects of Cryptowatch and how to use them for profitable trading.